# TYPO3 news extension, give editor possibility to select image for preview

Tags: editor, typo3, privileges, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I use TYPO3 v7.6.13 and news v5.3.1 ... I've set this up so that an old man can take care of the news, I added him as editor with very limited privileges and that works all fine.

what I cannot find is how to enable him to see the checkbox 'image metadata' so as to select an image as preview in the list ...

so far I did this:

```
main directory -> list view -> backend usergroup -> access lists
```

- activated news in tables (listing)
- activated news in tables (modify)
- in allowed excludefields -> news -> I ticked a few and expected to find it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox can be found within **File reference**: `Show in preview views (showinpreview)`

Answer (score 2):

This checkbox should be located under "File Reference" instead of the news fields.